# How to reject unqualified parameter in constructor of Java?

Tags: java, constructor, parameter-passing

I got a problem, I am writing a Java class, its contractor will need two parameters, parameter is an image object - BufferedImage, I need check the image's width and height.

> One rule is - imageOne's wight need be the same as imageTwo, if not I
>   want the application to stop and raise message to tell user that the
>   two images are not good(unqualified).

I guess there should be one regular way to handle my idea in Java, maybe I need rasie an exception?

Sorry, adding part of code I wrote:

```
public class Replacer { // This class to merge two images, so it need they have same width.

private BufferedImage smallImage;
private BufferedImage bigImage;

Replacer(BufferedImage smallImage, BufferedImage bigImage) {

    // I want the smallImage and bigImage have same weight        

    this.setSmallImage(smallImage);
    this.setBigImage(bigImage);

    wOfNewScreen = bigImage.getWidth();
    hOfSmallImage = smallImage.getHeight();
    hOfBigImage = bigImage.getHeight();

    if (wOfNewScreen != samllImage.getWidth()) {

        System.out.println("ERROR: The two images don't have same width!!");
    }

}
```

//...
  }

Can someone help? Thanks in advance!

Reed

Comment: ok and for this assignment, what have you done so far?

Comment: some code my lord...

Comment: Why to put exception just give an error message using `JOptionPane`. Have a look at this link: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct! An exception would be the best option here.

Instead your line that prints an error message just do this.

```
throw new IllegalArgumentException("Both pictures need to be of same width");
```

Answer (score 1):

Yup, an Exception works, especially for a constructor.  Good call =)

Another option, check out the [factory method pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern).